# SAM RestAPI auth when using external openAPI DefinitionBody

Tags: aws-serverless, aws-sam

I'm having trouble creating an AWS SAM RestAPI with the following goals

1. OpenAPI yaml definition file
2. Interactive SwaggerUI endpoint
3. api-key authetication

I have been able to (1) use an external openapi yaml file by using the DefinitionBody property of the AWS::Serverless::Api instead of directly specifying the endpoints in the in my template.yaml

```
 ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      DefinitionBody:
        Fn::Transform:
          Name: AWS::Include
          Parameters:
            Location: openapi.yaml
```

I accomplished (2) swaggerUI by setting up a nodejs lambda function that serves the /docs endpoint using serverless-express and swagger-ui-express following a [helpful blog/tutorial](https://itnext.io/exploring-an-openapi-swagger-first-approach-to-serverless-development-on-aws-d19f0e9ca257)

I can't figure out how to get (3) auth working as I'm running into "This is a limitation in SAM's authorizer support. It only works with inline swagger definitions and AWS::Include is not supported" from the discussion [here](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/664)

**Summary** My 3 goals for a RestAPI deployed by AWS-SAM must be common but it feels like I can't have all three. I see 2 options of moving forward but hope there are more I don't know about

- Use an inline swagger definition instead of the DefinitionBody property so that auth works with the ApiGateway with the downside that I have to write my API in the SAM template.yaml
- Keep the swagger definition in a separate file and roll my own API-key authorization

Is there a different approach?